# How to extract Curly Braces Vector from Cell String in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, vector, char, cell

I have the following string (char of 1X48) in cell in Matlab

> { {1 , 0 , 0 } , { 0 , 1 , 0 } , { 0 , 0 , 1 } }.

I am trying to get three separate strings in new line with just space, so that data will look like

> 1 0 0
>
> 0 1 0
>
> 0 0 1

I will really appreciate if anyone has any idea to covert in matlab.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) function

In your case you can try something like this,

temp  = { {1 , 0 , 0 } , { 0 , 1 , 0 } , { 0 , 0 , 1 } };
out = [cell2mat(temp{1, 1});  cell2mat(temp{1, 2});  cell2mat(temp{1, 3})]

I hope it will help!!

Comment: Thanks! This is really help me. herohuyongtao also suggested to use strjoin fuction to get the oupput in string.

Comment: I am having issue with reading string from cell in matlab. I have excel spreadsheet which I am reading in matlab using xlsread. I have tried using eval() to convert above string to cell but somehow it is not breaking into individual cell. I cann't perform the method you have mentioned. Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: It would be great if you can please share any sample data of excel datasheet but in general to convert a "string to cell" better to use str2mat and mat2cell

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html):

```
a = { {1 , 0 , 0 } , { 0 , 1 , 0 } , { 0 , 0 , 1 } };
b = strjoin(a, ' ')
```

Then:

```
b =

1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

---

**Edit:** if you want to get new lines involved, you can use

```
b = [strjoin(a(1), ' '); strjoin(a(2), ' '); strjoin(a(3), ' ');]
```

Then:

```
b =

1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

---

**P.S.:** `strjoin` works in MATLAB R2013b. For earlier versions, you can download the `strjoin` function from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31862-strjoin).

Comment: Thanks! This is also help me. This is working as well.